# jqgrid not loading data  in server acugis but locally all works perfect

Tags: javascript, xml, jqgrid

Hello I am having troubles with my jqgrid, my jqgrid loads an xml file locally(locally all works ), but in the server does not load anything, I tried with every code I found on the internet but I dont know why It is not loading the data in the grid, the jqgrid always shows a message that says Loading... and I wait some time, and then It stopped and does not load anything, can someone help?? locally works but in the server acugis not, please help

this is my code:

```
$("#listaRedCuidadana").jqGrid({
            treeGrid: true,
            treeGridModel : 'adjacency',
            ExpandColumn : 'distrito',
            url: '../../red_ciudadana/controller/controllerMostrarRedCuidadana.php',
            treeReader: {
                level_field: 'level',
                parent_id_field: 'parent_id',
                leaf_field: 'isLeaf',
                expanded_field: 'expanded'
            },
            datatype: "xml",
            mtype: "POST",
            colNames:["id_ciudadano","Distrito","Seccion","Rol","Clave Electoral","Nombre","Apellido Paterno","Apellido Materno"],
            colModel:[
                 {name:'id_ciudadano',index:'id_ciudadano', width:1,hidden:true,key:true},
                 {name:'distrito',index:'distrito',align:"left"},
                 {name:'seccion',index:'seccion', width:60,align:"center"},
                 {name:'rol',index:'rol', width:150,align:"left"},
                 {name:'clave_electoral',index:'clave_electoral', width:150,align:"center"},
                 {name:'nombre',index:'nombre', width:100,align:"left"},
                 {name:'apaterno',index:'apaterno', width:100,align:"left"},
                 {name:'amaterno',index:'amaterno', width:100,align:"left"}
            ],
            width:'916',
            /*autowidth:true,*/
            height:'auto', 
            pager: '#pager',
            caption:"COORDINADORES DISTRITALES",
            onSelectRow: function(id){
                var clv=$('#listaRedCuidadana').jqGrid('getCell',id,4);
                mostrarDetallesCuidadano(clv);
                initMapa();

            }
        });
        $("#listaRedCuidadana").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

and my .php file

```
<?php
require_once '../../sesion/model/clsSesion.php';
require_once '../../red_ciudadana/model/modelRedCuidadana.php';

if ( stristr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"],"application/xhtml+xml") ) {
        header("Content-type: application/xhtml+xml;charset=utf-8"); } else {
        header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['nodeid'])==FALSE) {
    $node =0;
}
else{
    $node = (integer)$_REQUEST["nodeid"];
}
$clsJqGrid = new redCuidadana();
$et = ">";
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?$et\n";
echo "<rows>";
echo "<page>1</page>";
echo "<total>1</total>";
echo "<records>1</records>";

if($node >0) { //check to see which node to load
   $wh = 'parent_id='.$node; // parents
   //$n_lvl = $n_lvl+1; // we should ouput next level
} else {
   //$wh = 'ISNULL(parent_id)'; 
   $wh ='parent_id=0';// roots
}
$mostrarRegistros= $clsJqGrid->mostrarRegistros($wh);
foreach ($mostrarRegistros as $row){
   echo "<row>";         
   echo "<cell>".$row["id_ciudadano"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["distrito"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["seccion"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["rol"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["clave_electoral"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["nombre"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["apaterno"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["amaterno"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell>".$row["level"]."</cell>";
   echo "<cell><![CDATA[".$row["parent_id"]."]]></cell>";
   if($row["level"] == "2"){echo "<cell>"."true"."</cell>";}
   else{echo "<cell>".$row["isLeaf"]."</cell>";}
   echo "<cell>".$row["expanded"]."</cell>";
   echo "</row>";
}
echo "</rows>";
?>
```

Comment: any ideas I try almost everything

Comment: Have you tried a JavaScript debugger such as firebug to verify that the XML is received by the browser, and that it is formatted the same as the XML that you are loading locally?

Comment: I tried but my controller is not loading anything, It gets stuck

Comment: So your controller never returned any XML to your grid? If so, did you get an error message in the server logs?

Comment: how can I check the server logs?

Comment: It depends on your platform and how you have PHP configured. On Linux you can start by looking in `/var/log/httpd`

Comment: any other ideas that can affect??

Comment: Not without an error log or some other indication of what is happening at run time.

Comment: I dont get an error message in the server log

Comment: what is your php filename (make sure case of all letters), have you tried to access jour php file directly without jqgrid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** try to simply echo sample xml from php without any logic performed and see if it is received by JS script;

**2.** as it was said, try to access PHP script directly in your browser and see if it returns valid result;

**3.** try to debug your code in chrome (not only in ff:firebug), these are both great tools and sometimes chrome can show what ff missed (and vise versa).

These steps will help you to isolate and find problem. If you'll have all these bullets above checked and problem still there - provide results in topic, so we'll have oportunity to help you.

Cheers and good luck ;)